# How do I remove property from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

ay I create an object as follows:

```
let myObject = {
  "ircEvent": "PRIVMSG",
  "method": "newURI",
  "regex": "^http://.*"
};
```

How should I remove the property regex to end up with new myObject as follows?

```
let myObject = {
  "ircEvent": "PRIVMSG",
  "method": "newURI"
};
```

Comment: removed python tag , as looks like its unrelated

Comment: Why the Python and C++ tags??

Comment: `delete myObject.regex`

Comment: [This is already documentated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try - delete myObject.regex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObject = {
  "ircEvent": "PRIVMSG",
  "method": "newURI",
  "regex": "^http://.*"
};

delete myObject.regex;
console.log(myObject);
```

The delete operator deletes both the value of the property and the property itself.
You can check in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp